# How do I stop Play Store from randomly opening when I'm in other apps?

Tags: google-play-store

Play Store is randomly opening when I'm in another app. It is simply showing me an app it thinks I would like, even though I haven't initiated any action on Play Store. I'm running Jelly Bean on a Motorola Razr Maxx.

Comment: I don't know of any legitimate software that does this. It sounds like you've got some malware there. Look under "Security>Device Administration>Device Administrators" to see if anything you've recently downloaded has placed itself here. That'll give you a start to removing it.

Comment: I second wbogacz in his suspicion. If there're any apps you remember having installed right before this begun, one of those is the most likely "culprit". Same advice then: Try uninstalling it and see whether the trouble is gone. If so, avoid apps from that dev in the future.

Comment: Thanks - I don't see anything there except "Motorola Device Policy" and "Android Device Manager". I doubt it is one of these that's the problem. I'm going to just uninstall the app where I'm having the issue. Hopefully that will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you clicking on ads inside apps? Because they would pop-up Play Store immediately. Remove all those apps which pops-up ads very frequently. If no - try signing out of the Play Store and stop it forcibly using App Manager. Then start it and login again. Post what happened.