# Why is the bURLy app no longer visible in the Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

[Dan Hulme](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/12442/dan-hulme) posted [a (deleted) answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81419/how-do-i-stop-play-store-from-randomly-opening-when-im-in-other-apps/81428#81428) on [How do I stop Play Store from randomly opening when I'm in other apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/81419/44325), mentioning an app called bURLY.

> I made an app [**bURLy**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.burly&referrer=ase81419) which lets you control what your phone does when an app tries to open a web link, such as to a Play Store app page. Even when other apps (such as the Play Store app) can open the link directly, it lets you preview what link will open, and create rules. You can make a rule to automatically ignore links to apps on Google Play, except when you allow it first.

However, it is no longer visible on the Play Store. Why?

Answer (score 1):

After a career change a few years ago I stopped updating these apps. When GDPR came in, Google required all app developers to update their apps' privacy policies to show GDPR compliance, even if the apps weren't collecting any personal data etc. Because I didn't update the apps' privacy policy, Google removed them from the Play Store. Because I wasn't logging into my developer account and keeping track, I didn't find out until months afterwards.

If I get around to it I might dig out the source code and publish it somewhere, so any interested party is able to update the apps and maybe to keep developing them.

Thanks for your interest! If people had been that interested at the time I might have been able to keep developing bURLy and other apps.